# In Python what's some other ways to write a if x==1 or x==5 or x==10...?

Tags: python, if-statement

I often end up writing code like

```
if x == 1 or x == 5 or x == 10 or x == 22 :
    pass
```

In English it seems redundant to keep repeating `x`, is there an easier or shorter way to write out an if-statement like that?

Maybe checking of existence of `x`'s value in a tuple `( 1, 5, 10, 22, )` or something?

Comment: Yeah, `if x in [1, 50, 10, 22]` is simpler to write and read

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you are right - either in a tuple or (if this check is made repeatedly) in a set.

So either do

```
if x in (1, 5, 10, 22):
    pass
```

or, if you do this check often and the number of values is large enough,

```
myset = set((1, 5, 10, 22))

[...]

if x in myset:
    pass
```

The `myset` stuff is the more useful, the more values you want to check. 4 values are quite few, so you can keep it simple. 400 values and you should use the set...

Another aspect, as pointed out by Marcin, is the necessary hashing for lookup in the set which may be more expensive than linearly searching a list or tuple for the wanted value.

Comment: In Python 2.7/3.*, you can also use a set literal: `{1, 5, 10, 22}`. In Python 3.2+, this even optimizes to use a `frozenset` transparently if you're just doing an `in` check (though not if you're saving the result in a variable).

Comment: +1 for first to suggest set, but I have to agree with Dougal that you should use the new syntax if possible.

Comment: `set((1, 5, 10, 22))` works in more versions than `{1, 5, 10, 22}` and really isn't all that more readable IMHO.

Comment: The set is only likely to be better (faster) if it's a very large set of objects being checked, because of the overhead of hashing.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `in` with a collection:

```
if x in [1, 5, 10, 22]:
     # etc...

if x in {1, 5, 10, 22}:  # New syntax for creating sets  
     # etc...
```

Note that this will create a new list every time the line executes. If efficiency is a concern, create the collection only once and reuse it.

Comment: ... or a set, as I wrote. Not so urgent with 4 values, more urgent with 40, 400 or 4000...

Comment: However, a tuple is more common and a set is semantically nicer even discounting the performance beneifts both have (depending on the Python version in the latter case).

Comment: @glglgl: Oh yes, a set is a better idea. Tuple is commonly used, but I think it's not semantically the most appropriate type.

Answer (score 2):

If you need good performance and are going to repeat the same comparison several times, use a set:

```
s = frozenset([1, 5, 10, 22]) # at the beginning

if x in s: # in your code
    pass
```

Comment: Of course, for small data sets a tuple may be faster (no need to hash, simpler data structure, no collision risk) and in Python 3.2, you get this optimization for free (even better, the frozenset is created only once) if you use a set literal in the condition. Also, same terms and conditions as with all performance issues: (1) Measure wether you need to optimize this. (2) Do #2 again! (3) Really sure? (4) Well, fine! Go collect your choices and benchmark them well.

Comment: So creating a `frozenset`, is faster than creating a regular `list`, and a `set`?